# Infinite scroll Ionic 2 error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement infinite scroll on my application but I am getting an error of `Property "then" does not exist on type "void"`. This is coming up in my text editor and in console when reaching the bottom of the page. This is pulling from a http get which is

```
perpage:number = 50;

loadCategory1(start:number=0) {
  var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=////&_app_key=////";

  if (this.Category1) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.Category1);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(url + "&allowedAllergy[]=396^Dairy-Free&allowedAllergy[]=393^Gluten-Free&maxResult=" + this.perpage + "&start=" + start)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.Category1 = data.matches;
        resolve(this.Category1);
      });
  });
}
```

The relevant code is

```
export class Category1Page {
  public api: any;
  private start:number=0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiAuthentication: ApiAuthentication) {
    this.loadRecipes();
  }

  loadRecipes(){
    this.apiAuthentication.loadCategory1(this.start)
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
  } 

  doInfinite(infiniteScroll:any) {
     console.log('doInfinite, start is currently '+this.start);
     this.start+=50;

     this.loadRecipes().then(()=>{
       infiniteScroll.complete();
     });
  }
}
```

HTML

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Any pointers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property "then" does not exist on type "void"

Your `loadRecipes` method is not returning anything (so it's void) and you're trying to call `then()...` in

```
this.loadRecipes().then(()=>{
       infiniteScroll.complete();
     });
```

Try by adding the `return` keyword like this:

```
loadRecipes(){
    return this.apiAuthentication.loadCategory1(this.start)
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
  }
```